# ExpressMapper - mapping/cloning enums - InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, enums

I am currently facing performance problems in a solution using EmitMapper. I would like to change the implementation of my IMapper to ExpressMapper due to performance and the fact that it is actively maintained.

My problem comes down to mapping Enums and the fact that enums should not be cast directly, as this will generate an InvalidCastException.

The solution is very generic and dynamic in nature and my primary ExpressMapper implementation contains the following method:

```
public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource src)
{
    return src.Map<TSource, TDestination>();
}
```

Having 2 identical Customer classes in different namespaces looking like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CustomerType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum CustomerType
{
    Company,
    Private,
    Government
}
```

I created a simple MSTest:

```
[TestClass]
public class ExpressMapperTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleMap()
    {
        // Arrange
        var myMapper = new MyMapper();
        Mappings.Source.Customer sourceCustomer = new Mappings.Source.Customer {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Type = Mappings.Source.CustomerType.Company
        };

        // Act
        var targetCustomer = myMapper.Map<Mappings.Source.Customer, Mappings.Target.Customer>(sourceCustomer);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(sourceCustomer.Name, targetCustomer.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual((int)sourceCustomer.Type, (int)targetCustomer.Type);
    }

}
```

The result is:

> Test method ExpressMapperTest.ExpressMapperTest.SimpleMap threw
>   exception:  System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from
>   'Mappings.Source.CustomerType' to 'Mappings.Target.CustomerType'.
>
> at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType,
>   IFormatProvider provider) at
>   System.Enum.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider
>   provider) at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type
>   conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) at
>   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType) at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Customer , Customer ) at
>   ExpressMapper.TypeMapperBase`2.MapTo(T src, TN dest) in
>   C:\SourceCode\ExpressMapper\ExpressMapper NET40\TypeMapperBase.cs:line
>   243    at ExpressMapper.MappingServiceProvider.MapInternal[T,TN](T
>   src, TN dest, Boolean dynamicTrial) in
>   C:\SourceCode\ExpressMapper\ExpressMapper
>   NET40\MappingServiceProvider.cs:line 273    at
>   ExpressMapper.MappingServiceProvider.MapInternal[T,TN](T src, TN dest,
>   Boolean dynamicTrial) in C:\SourceCode\ExpressMapper\ExpressMapper
>   NET40\MappingServiceProvider.cs:line 299    at
>   ExpressMapper.MappingServiceProvider.Map[T,TN](T src) in
>   C:\SourceCode\ExpressMapper\ExpressMapper
>   NET40\MappingServiceProvider.cs:line 241    at
>   ExpressMapper.Mapper.Map[T,TN](T src) in
>   C:\SourceCode\ExpressMapper\ExpressMapper NET40\Mapper.cs:line 38
>   at ExpressMapper.Extensions.ExpressmapperExtensions.Map[T,TN](T
>   source) in C:\SourceCode\ExpressMapper\ExpressMapper
>   NET40\ExpressmapperExtensions.cs:line 11

Any solution using the CustomerType enum type directly is invalid, as it is a dynamic system comprised of pluggable components having each their own object graphs to be mapped, e.g. from a CustomerProxy to a Customer component (domain objects).

I have tried a bunch of approaches including implementing a CustomMapper to map enums in a generic way, however I have not hit the jackpot. - I am wondering if the only way forward is a change to ExpressMapper itself.

The correct way of mapping between standard enums as above would be:
Mappings.Source.CustomerType -> int -> Mappings.Target.CustomerType

.... which would not throw InvalidCast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressmapper supports implicit conversions by using IConvertible interface which is not the case here. I've created [Github issue](https://github.com/expressmapper/ExpressMapper/issues/63) just to take into consideration if it is the valid case to implement.
So far you have many alternatives but the easiest and the fastest one is:

```
Mapper.Register<Mappings.Source.Customer, Mappings.Target.Customer>()
   .Member(dst => dst.Type, src => (Mappings.Target.CustomerType)((int)src.Type));
```

After registration above just use your client mapping code.
Thanks for your valuable input!

UPDATE: Expressmapper 1.8 supports enum mappings by using integer values as a mapping criteria from enums.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above is not viable in our solution, as we get the enum types dynamically based on a series of components. We would have to nonstop extend the registered mappings with new enums, which would grow exponentially and create a huge maintenance overhead.
I already tried a similar approach using:
Mapper.RegisterCustom<Mappings.Source.Customer, Mappings.Target.Customer, EnumMapper>();

Still, it is necessary to do this on the top level as AnyEnum -> underlying type -> AnyEnum.... assuming the enums are the same, but in different namespaces/assemblies.

Comment: Note: I know that best practices dictate to have such common enums in a Central Data Model used across the solutions, which would let the enum to simply pass through inside DefaultType(). However this is currently not possible in the organization :-(

Comment: Bo Stig Christensen - Gotcha! Let me think what I can do. I'll get back to you soon!

Comment: It has been implemented and will be supported in Expressmapper 1.8